# How can I create a new SequenceGenerator for generating unique values?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'd like to know how to create my own custom id generator for JPA. Instead of just having a generator which is a numeric incrementer, I'd like to create an alphanumeric, case-sensitive generator, akin to how URL shorteners keep track of sites.

For example, URL shorteners don't use numerical keys because they are inefficient in comparison to a case-sensitive alphanumeric generator. Essentially, something like `urlshortener.com/20` could be shortened as `urlshortener.com/t`. This difference becomes exponentially better as numbers increase, as it's 10^n vs 62^n where n is the number of digits available.

How can I implement this in JPA as a SequenceGenerator?

Comment: if you have a requirement that requires you to have a no numeric ID then that is a flawed requirement. IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing in the database this is not more efficient. For display you can use Base64 or Base32 encoding.

Comment: +1 for smart idea.But why would one display a different value to what is in database .

Comment: How are URL shorteners doing this? They're obviously not using Base64 or Base32, as these have irregular characters such as equals signs.

Comment: "why would one display a different value to what is in database" -- for the answer to that question, please to be reading up on the MVC (Model View Controller) pattern.  How one presents a view of the data is up to the VIEW, not to the data model.  So I agree.  It's better to keep your primary keys as integers if at all possible.

Comment: Ok. Well here's the issue: at some point, these values have to be looked up in a database. I could store the primary ID as a long, then work up some logic to create a second column which will store the number expressed in my notation. Is that the best route? Even still, when someone hits a URL, I'll do a `select * from urls where path=A5cDfQ`.

Comment: @Shazeb: because you may want to have a shorter URL, while using the simpler handling of a normal Sequence in the database.

Comment: @TK Base64 or Base32 can be decoded back to the original code. As long as the function is reversible, it really does not matter if you post the original value or the encoded one (but be coherent).

Comment: Alright, but I still don't know how to create a `SequenceGenerator` :(